# Embed R Console on your web site or your application

Tags: r

How to add **R Console** to your desktop application or on your web site? There are several free online courses like "Try Y" where you write R code and you can run it and interpreter puts console output right there on the web site. Obviously, it's programmaticaly available. I wonder what's the best practice in implementing it.

Comment: like the `R fiddle` ?

Comment: exactly. I just did not want to put any links because it could have been considered as an ad.